# Firebase: Nested onSnapshot returns "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to nest an onSnapshot to handle initial loading of data from two different documents. Here's my full function:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        return db
        .collection("accounts").doc(currentAccount)
        .collection("farms").doc(currentFarm)
        .collection("sensors").doc(currentSensor)
        .onSnapshot((sensorSnapshot) => {

            // Save sensor metadata
            const sensorData = sensorSnapshot.data();
            setSensorData(sensorData);
            console.log(sensorData);
            const sensorReadingsId = sensorData.sensorReadingsId.toString();

            // Problem starts 
            db.collection("readings").doc(sensorReadingsId).onSnapshot((readingsSnapshot) => {
                const list = [];
                readingsSnapshot.forEach((reading) => {
                    const { name, value1, value2, value3, voltage } = reading.data();
                    list.push({
                        id: reading.id,
                        name,
                        value1,
                        value2,
                        value3,
                        voltage
                    });
                });
                setReadingsData(list);
                console.log(readingsData);

            });

            // Finally, finish
            setLoading(false);

        });
    }, []);
```

Which gives me an error: *undefined is not a function (near '...readingsSnapshot.forEach...')*

If I comment out the `db.collection("readings")...` part, it operates as expected. I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong with the second onSnapshot. How do I fix this?

Comment: Note that you are leaking the inner snapshot listener by ignoring the return value of onSnapshot.  Your outer listener is fine, but your inner listeners are leaking.  You'll need to find a way around that to make sure they are unsubscribed correctly when no longer needed.

Comment: Would it be better to have them in separate useEffects? Then I could run the second one only when sensorData updates? Not sure what approach is best here.

Comment: I don't have an opinion about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readingsSnapshot` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) type object, representing a single snapshot of the document referenced by `db.collection("readings").doc(sensorReadingsId)`.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it doesn't have a forEach method, as there is nothing to iterate like there is with [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

If you want to work with the fields of the document of that snapshot, just call `data()` on it directly.

```
db.collection("readings").doc(sensorReadingsId).onSnapshot((readingsSnapshot) => {
    const { name, value1, value2, value3, voltage } = readingsSnapshot.data();
    // do what you want from here
});
```